# PHP/HTML Form retrieving value

Tags: orm

I have a PHP page with the following code on it for a select box.

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $a?>" name="test2" id="test2">
<select name="test" id="test" onchange="parentNode.submit()">
<?php if($_POST['submitted'] == true){ ?>
                    <?php $a = echo $_POST['test'];?> 
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <option value="">-- select Video --</option>
                <?php } ?>

<?php  foreach ($pages as $page):

    // Prepare data for each page being listed...
    $title = $th->entities($page->getCollectionName());
    $url = $nh->getLinkToCollection($page);
    $target = ($page->getCollectionPointerExternalLink() != '' && $page->openCollectionPointerExternalLinkInNewWindow()) ? '_blank' : $page->getAttribute('nav_target');
    $target = empty($target) ? '_self' : $target;
    $description = $page->getCollectionDescription();
    $description = $controller->truncateSummaries ? $th->shorten($description, $controller->truncateChars) : $description;
    $description = $th->entities($description); 


    <h3 class="ccm-page-list-title">
    <option value="<?php  echo $url ?>">
        <?php  echo $title ?>
    </option>
    </h3>


<?php  endforeach; ?>
 </select>
<input type="submit" value="go" name="Watch Video" />
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
</form>
```

The above form Has the Page name as the option and the Value as the URL link. Now what I want is for the selected /option to redirect the users on submit to the URL Value (see below option example)

```
<option value="/index.php/video-gallery/latin-america/mtw-2011-destination-report-mexico-city/">MtW 2011 - Destination Report: Mexico City</option>
```

So what I want is the page to redirect to the selected values URL I am close its just setting the selected value on submit to the Variable The Line doesn't work `<?php $a = echo $_POST['test'];?>`

Is this even possible without JavaScript or redirecting to another redirect.php pages which looks up the value for the redirects  then loads that page?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible without JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like -

```
   // do your redirect here
   header('Location: '. $_POST["test"]);
   exit();
```

but JQuery would be the best way to go about it